# Converting rows of dictionaries into separate pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe of two columns. One of the two has a value of a dictionary consisting of several keys and values. I'd like to expand these dictionary keys to separate columns. Is this possible within pandas?

```
In [1]:print df
Out[2]:
  ID    column_2
0  1    {u'color':'blue',u'counts':10}
1  3    {u'color':'red',u'counts':30}
2  10   {u'color':'purple',u'counts':12}
...
```

to the following desired output:

```
   ID  color   counts
0   1  'blue'      10
1   3  'red'       30
2   10  'purple'   12
```

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you can do the following:

```
In [3]: pd.DataFrame(df.col2.values.tolist())
Out[3]: 
    color  counts
0    blue      10
1     red      30
2  purple      12
```

So just hack it together using `concat` from there:

```
In [4]: pd.concat((df.ID, pd.DataFrame(df.col2.values.tolist())),axis=1)
Out[4]: 
   ID   color  counts
0   1    blue      10
1   3     red      30
2  10  purple      12
```

**Timings**:

```
In [132]: %timeit (pd.concat((df.ID, pd.DataFrame(df.column_2.tolist())),axis=1))
1 loop, best of 3: 339 ms per loop

In [133]: %timeit (pd.concat((df.ID, pd.DataFrame(df.column_2.values.tolist())),axis=1))
1 loop, best of 3: 322 ms per loop

In [134]: %timeit pd.concat([df, df.column_2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))], axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 7s per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,3,10],
                   'column_2':[{u'color':'blue',u'counts':10},
                               {u'color':'red',u'counts':30},
                               {u'color':'purple',u'counts':12}]})

df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)
#[300000 rows x 3 columns]
print (df)
```

Comment: Faster is use `pd.concat((df.ID, pd.DataFrame(df.col2.values.tolist())),axis=1)`

Comment: I think because it works with numpy arrays better, try it ;)

Comment: @jezrael Sure, but I would have assumed that `Series.tolist()` simply would be `Series.values.tolist()` under the hood anyway...

Comment: it is difference - `Series.tolist()` tolist works with Series and `Series.values.tolist()` withs with numpy array - this is 2 differens functions I think

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you have a dictionary as a datatype in your dataframe (probably doesn't make sense), this does the job:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df, df.column_2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))], axis=1)
df2

   ID                           column_2   color  counts
0   1    {'counts': 10, 'color': 'blue'}    blue      10
1   3     {'counts': 30, 'color': 'red'}     red      30
2  10  {'counts': 12, 'color': 'purple'}  purple      12
```

Then you can just do `df2 = df2[[x for x in df2.columns if x != 'column_2']]`

---

Do make sure that you have an actual dict in your column, and not a string representation of a dict. For example, when I load you data it is a string representation so I have to change that:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.column_2 = df.column_2.apply(lambda x: eval(x))
```